# Simple way to wipe a partition in Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

Is there some simple way to wipe a partition in Windows 8?

I don't need military-grade security, but basic undelete tools should be unable to recover the data, so simply "overwriting everything once" should work.

I know that there are various tools available for this, but is there a built-in way to do that? For example, will re-formatting the hard drive (not "quick format") overwrite everything?

Answer (score 0):

*(Found the solution myself. Since answering your own questions is encouraged here, I'll just do that instead of removing the question.)*

Starting with Windows Visa, [a full format overwrites everything with zeroes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941961):

> The format command behavior has changed in Windows Vista. By default in Windows Vista, the format command writes zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed. In Windows XP and in earlier versions of the Windows operating system, the format command does not write zeros to the whole disk when a full format is performed.